# How do I use codepush with Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I'm trying to use codepush with Ionic 1. Ideally it should just work when I follow the example for regular cordova app. However mine is throwing an error as if it doesn't recognize codePush. Here's a snippet of it. Can anyone tell you how do I inject codepush properly?
 note: I did cordova plugin add

```js
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, locationService,Ordyx) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        //window.cordova.plugins.brightness.setBrightness(1, function(){}, function(){});
        codePush.sync();
```